# Area interpretation of integrals for the floor function

Tags: calculus

Use the area interpretation of integrals to prove that;
$$\int_{0}^n \lfloor t \rfloor dt = \frac{(\lfloor n\rfloor-1)\lfloor n\rfloor}{2}$$
for all integers n $\ge$ 0, and hence find a formula for $\int_{0}^x \lfloor t \rfloor dt$.

I assume for the second part that the formula is 
$$\int_{0}^x \lfloor t \rfloor dt = \frac{(\lfloor x\rfloor-1)\lfloor x\rfloor}{2}$$

For the first part I have assumed that since n is an integer $\lfloor n\rfloor$ = n

Therefore we have $$\int_{0}^n \lfloor t \rfloor dt = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$$ This is the solution to that summation of (i-1) from i=1 to n if I am remembering correctly, and matches the area of all the rectangles from 0 to n right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Okay just to clarify I am confused with the first at of how to actually use the area interpretation. The duplicate only really deals with the second part!

Comment: $F$ is not defined so there is no formula for it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify that F(x) is equal to the integral for the step function between 0 and x

Comment: Well then yes you just want the area of the rectangles because the graph is the outline of those rectangles and so clearly the area under the graph is the sum of the rectangles' areas. the rectangle heights are the integers from $0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help!